# Abstracting lat and lon coordinates names?

Tags: coordinates, python-xarray

I am trying to use xarray on CMIP6 (CF-Metadata compliant) datasets. I simply need to plot the lats and lons(as dots) for various datasets I have processed with cdo(Climate Data Operators). The CF Metadata standard does not enforce common names for the lat and lon variables. Does xarray provide a means to abstract away this problem? Is there a way I can use the lat an lon variables without having to explicitly use their names from the data files?

In the past I have done this by manually pattern matching on the dataset "coordinates" attribute. I was hoping xarray could do this automagically.

Comment: no, this is not supported in xarray - the xarray developers [take a pretty hard stance](//docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/getting-started-guide/faq.html#what-is-your-approach-to-metadata) against automatic inference using metadata like this, opting instead for domain-agnostic flexibility. However, there are a large and growing number of ["ecosystem" libraries](//docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/ecosystem.html) which may do this. I've never used it, but [aospy](//aospy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#built-in-alternative-names), for one, looks like it does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Those links are very useful. These days, I lean hard on tools such as [Climate Data Operators](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo) to avoid writing unnecessary code.